# Python BeautifulSoup - Scrape Web Content Inside Iframes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

We have this URL: 
https://www.aliexpress.com/store/feedback-score/1665279.html

And the needed content is the "Feedback History" table, which is inside an iframe:

```
Feedback    1 Month 3 Months    6 Months
Positive (4-5 Stars)    154 562 1,550
Neutral (3 Stars)   8   19  65
Negative (1-2 Stars)    8   20  57
Positive feedback rate  95.1%   96.6%   96.5%
```

How do we extract it?

Comment: I think it's highly likely that you'll need mock browsers such as `selenium` and use `selenium.switch_to.frame()` as content of iframe will not load in requests, and the link to that iframe will most likely not work unless the session is kept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to obtain the `src` attribute of the `iframe`, and then request and parse its content:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/store/feedback-score/1665279.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
iframe_src = soup.select_one("#detail-displayer").attrs["src"]

r = s.get(f"https:{iframe_src}")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for row in soup.select(".history-tb tr"):
    print("\t".join([e.text for e in row.select("th, td")]))
```

Result:

```
Feedback        1 Month         3 Months        6 Months
Positive (4-5 Stars)    154     562     1,550
Neutral (3 Stars)       8       19      65
Negative (1-2 Stars)    8       20      57
Positive feedback rate  95.1%   96.6%   96.5%
```

Comment: ah, perfect.. Thanks Cody a million. I appreciate it.

Comment: Please change the URL to- https://www.aliexpress.com/store/feedback-score/1665279.html