# Get the iframe src link using Jsoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

I really need help. I'm trying to get the link as marked in the image with jsoup but I'm not able to get.

[image]

link of the site https://upvid.host/embed-okdfloukqche.html

Thank you.

Comment: I guess your problem, is that you are trying to access content inside an iframe. You have to open/request src of the top iframe first, and than you should parse the data inside it.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522364/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-web-content-inside-iframes](python-beautifulsoup-scrape-web-content-inside-iframes)

Comment: in fact after #document i'can't access data in side it (data in side #document )

Comment: That's right because it's another document embedded on the web page that you are trying to scrape. [traverse-iframe-using-jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234019/traverse-iframe-using-jsoup)

Comment: i try it but i can't access this link with jsoup because first iframe change again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by using webview and now I can get all the request.