# Extracting Scraped Web Content from iframe

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, iframe, beautifulsoup

Attempting to scrape the table at https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/zip-code-vaccination-data

I've looked at
[Python BeautifulSoup - Scrape Web Content Inside Iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522364/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-web-content-inside-iframes#) and have gotten this far but I don't know how to extract the information from `soup`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/zip-code-vaccination-data")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
iframe_src = '//static-assets.ny.gov/load_global_footer/ajax?iframe=true'

r = s.get(f"https:{iframe_src}")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

Website you're trying to **scrape** generates `<iframe>` dynamically with javascript so you need either something to automate browser actions like selenium, puppeteer or assign `<iframe>` url to a variable, because it seems to not change in the near future. Here is an url of your `<iframe>`:

`https://public.tableau.com/views/Vaccination_Rate_Public/NYSVaccinationRate?:embed=y&:showVizHome=n&:tabs=n&:toolbar=n&:device=desktop&showShareOptions=false&:apiID=host0#navType=1&navSrc=Parse`